# changing the footer of an embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so the idea is i want the bot to send an embed, then take the embed's content, change the footer then send it to **test** channel

this is the code i'm using:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  global test, log, bot_command
  test = bot.get_channel(868816978293452841)
  log = bot.get_channel(858700787815546930)
  bot_command = bot.get_channel(808734570283139162)
  print('bot is ready')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):



  if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    embed_old = discord.Embed(
      title= '''title''', 
      description= '''description''', 
      color= discord.Color.red()
      )
    embed_old.set_footer(text='old footer')
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed_old)



  if not len(message.embeds):
    return
  else:
    # embeds = message.embeds # return list of embeds
    embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0] # the message has only one embed so i'm using this instead of the last line


    for embed in embed_content_in_dict:
      print(embed.to_dict()) # print the content of embed in dict
      embed_new = discord.Embed(
          title= embed_content_in_dict.title, #old embed's title
          description= embed_content_in_dict.description, #old embed's descripton
          )
      embed_new.set_footer(text='new footer')
      await test.send(embed=embed_new)

  

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

this is what i get in the console:

```
bot is ready # on_ready

footer # this print is from the line 43 **print(embed)** but i don't know why it doesn't print the rest of the content

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 45, in on_message
    title= embed_content_in_dict.title, #old embed's title
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'title'
```

so my first problem is the bot doesn't get the information from the embed for somereason.. i think.. 
my second problem is.. i don't know how to call the embed's content.. like ffs all i thought of was

```
title = embed_content_in_dict.title
```

so my question is how can i make this code work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dictionary. Use the square brackets (`[]`) to get the keys.

```py
title = embed_content_in_dict["title"]
```